# Not able to get skype group chat as well as bot messages

Tags: skype-bots

When call this API then getting below error
https://skype.botframework.com/v3/conversations/29%3Adg_yugtechno/activities
{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Failed to decrypt conversation id"}}

Comment: I'm having this as well. Did you solve it?